# Hibernate/H2 foreign key throwing org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException

Tags: hibernate, exception, h2

I'm trying to use an H2 db for my unit testing.  My actual database is MYSql, so i'm using the MYSQL dialect with H2.  The problem appears to happen once the hbm files are read/loaded. The foreign keys/associations go out of whack as H2 or Hibernate try to alter the tables., or so it seems.

**DB scripts:**

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `amr` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `amr`;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `amr`.`classA`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `amr`.`classA` ;CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amr`.`classA` (
  `classA_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(56) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`classA_id`) );

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `amr`.`classB`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `amr`.`classB` ;CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amr`.`classB` (
  `classB_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `classA_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`classB_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_classB_service_provider_classA1` (`classA_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_classB_service_provider_classA1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`classA_id` )
    REFERENCES `amr`.`classA` (`classA_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

**Exception I receive:**

```
09-11 08:46:33 jdbc[2]: exception
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "FOREIGN" not found; SQL statement:
alter table amr.classB drop foreign key FKAF0F85CABD96B12B [42122-168]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:605)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseAlterTable(Parser.java:4874)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseAlter(Parser.java:4315)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:306)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1109)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcStatement.java:121)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcStatement.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.drop(SchemaExport.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1842)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
09-11 08:46:33 jdbc[2]: exception
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE AMR.CLASSB ADD INDEX FKAF0F85CABD96B12B (CLASSA_ID),[*] ADD CONSTRAINT FKAF0F85CABD96B12B FOREIGN KEY (CLASSA_ID) REFERENCES AMR.CLASSA (ID) "; SQL statement:
alter table amr.classB add index FKAF0F85CABD96B12B (classA_id), add constraint FKAF0F85CABD96B12B foreign key (classA_id) references amr.classA (id) [42000-168]
09-11 08:46:34 jdbc[2]: exception
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "FOREIGN" not found; SQL statement:
alter table amr.classB drop foreign key FKAF0F85CABD96B12B [42122-168]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:605)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseAlterTable(Parser.java:4874)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseAlter(Parser.java:4315)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:306)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1109)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcStatement.java:121)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcStatement.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.drop(SchemaExport.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.drop(SchemaExport.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:959)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.destroy(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:228)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.destroy(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:899)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
```

**hbm mappings:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
    <class name="ClassA" table="classA">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="id"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="56" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <set name="classBs" table="classB" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="classA_id" not-null="true"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="ClassB"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
    <class name="ClassB" table="classB">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="id"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="56" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="classA" class="ClassA" fetch="select">
            <column name="classA_id" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**H2 URL:**

```
jdbc:h2:~/db/amr_test;MODE=MYSQL;INIT=create schema if not exists test_db\\;runscript from 'classpath:amr_test_ddl.sql';DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

-------------------EDIT/Found issue----------------------------------

After pretty much starting back from scratch and reassessing everything, found out that I improperly added the below property to my context file:

create-drop

In one of the forums that guided to my H2 context configs pointed to using it as it "drops the schema after the session closes".

So my ignorance of this property has resulted in a lesson learned.

@Thomas Mueller - thanks very much for you time and assistance with this matter.

Comment: Does it work if you use the H2 dialect instead (and remove MODE=MYSQL)? I guess you anyway need to have two Hibernate configurations (one for test and one for production). Hibernate should be able to abstract database specific features so you don't need to care much if you are using a different database in production.

Comment: when I change to the h2 dialect, it is unhappy with my ddl syntax:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unknown data type: "FK_CLASSB_SERVICE_PROVIDER_CLASSA1"; SQL statement:
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amr`.`classB` (
  `classB_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `classA_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`classB_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_classB_service_provider_classA1` (`classA_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_classB_service_provider_classA1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`classA_id` )
    REFERENCES `amr`.`classA` (`classA_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: and yes, I have separate hibernate configs, but trying to maintain one set of db script files

Comment: I'm afraid H2 and MySQL are not 100% compatible. You could change the ddl script so the index and the foreign key are created after creating the table, using more standard SQL statements (ALTER TABLE).

Comment: yes, i tried doing that a little bit ago, and received the same exception.  Here is the ddl I used for classB:

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `amr`.`classB`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `amr`.`classB` ;CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amr`.`classB` (
  `classB_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `classA_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`classB_id`) );
    
ALTER TABLE `amr`.`classB`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`classA_id`) 
REFERENCES `amr`.`classA`(`classA_id`)

Answer (score 2):

You have used a script that only works for MySQL.
The following script should be more cross database, according to my test it works for H2, MySQL, and PostgreSQL (I didn't test other databases). I also replaced the MySQL specific `INT(11)` with `INT`. The script assumes the schema / database `amr` already exists:

```
drop table if exists amr.classB;
drop table if exists amr.classA;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS amr.classA (
    classA_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (classA_id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS amr.classB ( 
    classB_id INT(11) NOT NULL , 
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL , 
    classA_id INT(11) NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (classB_id)
);
CREATE INDEX fk_classB_service_provider_classA1 
    ON amr.classA(classA_id ASC);
ALTER TABLE amr.classB 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_classB_service_provider_classA1 
    FOREIGN KEY (classA_id) 
    REFERENCES amr.classA(classA_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Then, in the Hibernate configuration, use the H2 mode for H2.